# Runtime issue - Regex URLs from up to 150k lines of text.

Tags: php, regex, runtime

I am using regex to first extract urls from some file. The file can have up to 250k lines of text. Each line in the file is passed to an array value called `$column7`. Below is taking a lot longer than I had hoped. Extracting the urls for 20k lines can take up to 1min and for extracting the domains can take twice or 3 times as long which doesn't make sense to me since it takes the url results as an input so I would have expected it to be quicker. Is there anything I can do to greatly speed this up?

```
// EXTRACT URLS
$regex = '/(https?\:\/\/|www)[^(\"|\\\) ]+/i';
$urls = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($column7); ++$i) {
  preg_match_all($regex, $column7[$i], $matches[$i]);
  $urls = array_merge($urls, $matches[$i][0]);
}

// EXTRACT DOMAINS
$regex = '/(https?\:\/\/|www)[^\/ ]+/i';
$domains = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($urls); ++$i) {
  preg_match_all($regex, $urls[$i], $matches[$i]);
  $domains = array_merge($domains, $matches[$i][0]);
}
```

Comment: If in 1 min you are able to extract 20K lines i don't think there is any fast method than that..

Comment: So you are doing a `preg_match_all` line by line? Why? and what do you think about `[^(\"|\\\) ]+`?

Comment: Why using `array_merge`, doesn't `$urls[] = $matches[$i][0]` enough? And why `$matches[$i]` and not simply `$matches`?

Comment: Thanks revo thats a really good point. Regarding the match pattern I need to match based on my input.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can extract domain also in the first loop.

with a regex like this one :

```
/(?:https?\:\/\/|www)([^\/ ]+)[^(\"|\\\) ]+/i'
```

see : https://regex101.com/r/rUGOtj/1

where `([^\/ ]+)` is a matching group for your domain.

And you can access to this match group with $matches[$i][1]